# How start android default camera without showing chooser using react-native-image-crop-picker

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

i am using react-native-image-crop-picker library as camera but when i open camera getting chooser option to select any one camera app i want to directly open default camera without showing chooser options from react native

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
ImagePicker.openCamera({
  width: 300,
  height: 400,
  cropping: true,
}).then(image => {
 console.log(image);
});
```

Comment: with this solution i am getting chooser other camera app but i want to open only default android camera not other camera app

Answer (score 0):

You can directly invoke the function provided by react-native-image-crop
it is called openCamera for camera opening
you can use it as the following

```
ImagePicker.openCamera({
 ...your camera config
}).then(image => {
  console.log(image);
});
```

Comment: i want to open android default camera without showing options to choose from available camera app

Comment: yes, open camera will allow you to open the camera directly ( unless you have multiple camera apps)

Comment: i do have multiple camera app but i want to open default and open camera asking to choose the camera

Comment: Thats the default behaviour for the camera in any app bro